# A more efficient way using a loop through variables

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have multiple select elements. I currently get the values from the select elements and then put a string together and send them via ajax. Is there a way I could loop through the select elements and assign the value then. I've tried but to no avail.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/2Nxxp/1/

```
 // current way
var opt1 = $('select[name="opt1"]').val();
var newOpt = $('select[name="newOpt"]').val();
var anotherOpt = $('select[name="anotherOpt"]').val();
var randomOpt = $('select[name="randomOpt"]').val();
var opt = $('select[name="opt"]').val();
var newOpt1 = $('select[name="newOpt1"]').val();
var 1newOpt = $('select[name="1newOpt"]').val();

 // new way but not working
$.each([ 'opt1', 'newOpt', 'anotherOpt', 'randomOpt', 'opt', 'newOpt1', '1newOpt'], function( index, value ) {
     var ''+value+'' = $('select[name="'+value+'"]').val();
});

QueryString = '&opt1='+opt1+'&newOpt='+newOpt+'&anotherOpt='+anotherOpt+'&randomOpt='+randomOpt+'&opt='+opt+'&newOpt1='+newOpt1+'&1newOpt='+1newOpt;
```

Comment: it seems your fiddle is missing the html

Comment: If you're going to build your own querystring, make sure you are properly escaping the values. it's safer to instead build an object, then $.param the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an object that will stock the value. Then your "new way" will work :

```
var obj = {};
$.each([ 'opt1', 'newOpt', 'anotherOpt', 'randomOpt', 'opt', 'newOpt1', '1newOpt'], function( index, value ) {
     obj[value] = $('select[name="'+value+'"]').val();
});

QueryString = '&opt1='+obj.opt1+'&newOpt='+obj.newOpt+'&anotherOpt='+obj.anotherOpt+'&randomOpt='+obj.randomOpt+'&opt='+obj.opt+'&newOpt1='+obj.newOpt1+'&1newOpt='+obj.1newOpt;
```

Comment: I would have instead used `QueryString = $.param(obj)`, it's less code, more maintainable, and automatically escapes the values.

Comment: @KevinB that's alright, but i think the OP is still learning. This way, it allow him to know how objects work. Using `$.param` or `.serialize()` is probably a better solution, but i was showing why it wasn't working.

Comment: You could add before the loop: `var selects = 
    document.getElementsByTagName("select");`
 then in the `.each` use `selects`  instead of write each select name.

and modify the `obj[value]` assignment to:


    `obj[$(value)[0]['name']] = $(value).val();`

It will keep the "soul" of the answer/explanation and will it give  more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method:

```
QueryString = $('select').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = '';
$('select').each(function(){
    query+= '&' + this.name + '=' + this.value;
});
```

or

```
var query = {};
$('select').each(function(){
    query[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery already has a function to create a query string from a group of selected form elements, [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/). You could just do this:

```
QueryString = $('select[name="opt1"],select[name="newOpt"],select[name="anotherOpt"],select[name="randomOpt"],select[name="opt"],select[name="newOpt1"],select[name="1newOpt"]').serialize();
```

Or, if that's *all* of the `<select>` elements on your page, simplify it to:

```
QueryString = $('select').serialize();
```